Given that a flattening operation is used, why is it that a CNN does not have the same problem as vectorizing an image?
So a key motivation for using CNN is that if we were to vectorize an image and then feed it into a standard multilayer perceptron, that vectorized image would lose spatial information between pixels.
However, in a CNN, a vectorization routine (called flatten) is also used to vectorize the final output into something that can be used to feed into a fully connect or softmax layer.
How does the flattening operation in CNN not have the same problem as vectorizing an image? Wouldn't some cross channel information be lost whenever we flatten?

The hope is that all the necessary spatial information has been extracted before the flattening is done, so that the signals passing through the flatten either are non-spatial ("cat") or tagged with spatial information ("cat at the lower left")
